# Dependencies for Hector_Slam

Tags: slam, navigation, rasbperrypi, dependencies, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm trying to install hector_slam on a Raspberry Pi 2 (it has ROS Indigo Comm). I would follow the steps listed but I do not know what other dependencies to add it because at the end of catkin_make I have an error. How do I know what dependencies will be needed?
Can I install ROS Indigo Desktop on RPi 2? Thank you!

```
$ cd ros_catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git
$ sudo apt-get install *******WHAT DEPENDENCIES WILL BE NEEDED?*******
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226310/dependencies-for-hector_slam/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What @mig says. Also, if you installed ROS from .debs on your RPi2 you can just run

```
   sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam
```

for installing precompiled binaries.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-12**:
hmpf, forgot about the easy one ;-) +1